# My new relay is recorded in the wrong country

Tags: relays

On [relay search](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html) my new Tor relay's country is given as Ukraine.  In fact it's in Germany.  Also the AS given on relay search is wrong.

Have I configured the relay wrongly?  Can I change this so its country is correct?

This is significant, as a user wishing to avoid relays in Germany might get mine in error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change this. The country code is assigned to the relay by the association of its IP address in a "GeoIP" GeoLite2 database provided by MaxMind. Unfortunately these types of GeoIP assignments can be incorrect, and also become more out-of-date over time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have no chance to add a comment since I have too low reputation so far. But I would like to give a more exact answer to this question. Here is a very logical answer to your question, to complete the answer that @**Steve** gave you:

Your relay is using Tor version **0.4.3.6** which was released on **2020-07-09**, which uses GeoIP2 database "**Last updated based on December 3 2019 Maxmind GeoLite2 Country**" (read from source). If we then go further to [RIPE Database](https://apps.db.ripe.net/db-web-ui/query?bflag=true&dflag=false&rflag=true&searchtext=95.111.230.178&source=RIPE&types=inetnum), we can see that last update to your IP range was made on **2020-04-15**, which was after the date **2019-12-03** when your GeoIP2 database was released.

**Solution**:

Simply wait for Tor to update their [GeoIP2 database](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/).

PS. It is so easy to find people on Google by only using four keywords: [**Tor**, **Relay**, **Ukraine** and **Lark**](https://google.com/search?q=Tor%20Relay%20Ukraine%20Lark) :-D

Regards.

Comment: The country is chosen by the directory authorities rather than the relay itself, so if it requires a newer database, the authorities will need to update.

Comment: @Steve > So you mean that authority uses a database older than **2020-04-15**? That was about a half year ago. Interesting however. Are you a Tor developer? Just curious, since youre answering many questions in Tor community on this site.

Comment: No Tor versions have upgraded yet from the December 2019 database: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/commits/master/src/config/geoip. And I'm not a developer on either the Tor network or tor application, but I am familiar with some parts of it so just here answering questions when I can.

Comment: Great then! Hopefully they will update soon.

Comment: Thanks Steve and FearDC!  I am also a bit surprised that Tor is working from such an old GeoIP database - Maxmind update GeoLite2 every week.
I was a bit alarmed you could find out so much about my relay!  Googling those keywords didn't work for me, but if you just type "lark" into the Tor relay search ...

Answer (score 0):

It's OK - all the ip-to-geo databases do have their mistakes. If you need it to be as precise as it can - buy a paid GeoIP database and feed it to Tor, but even this time - it **will** have it's misses, just be prepared